# Insert ListBox into Collection

Tags: c#, mongodb, listbox

I have a ListBox with Multiple selected Items, and I try to insert into a collection into MongoDB

the Code

```
private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // add user into datagridview from MongoDB Colelction Watchtbl
        var client = new MongoClient("mongodb://servername:27017");
        var database = client.GetDatabase("WatchTblDB");
        var collectionWatchtbl = database.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("Watchtbl");

        var document = new BsonDocument {
            { "userId", UsersComboBox.SelectedItem.ToString() },
            { "wid", WIDTxt.Text.ToString() },
            { "name", NameComboBox.SelectedItem.ToString() },
            { "Symboles" , new BsonDocument
                {
                    foreach(var item in SymbolesListBox.SelectedItems)
                    { "Name", item.ToString() }
                },
            }
        };

        await collectionWatchtbl.InsertOneAsync(document);
    }
```

> the collection
>
> > Watchtbl : id, userId, wid, name, Symboles

This is an example for Find collection

> { "_id" : ObjectId("57cd794b287173b3468f6a34"), "userId" :
>   "57cae1c3613fb185524da68f", "wid" : "1350", "name" : "bought stock",
>   "Symboles" : [ { "Name" : "AAA" }, { "Name" : "BSI" } ] } 
>   { "_id" : ObjectId("57cd79ab287173b3468f6a35"), "userId" :
>   "57cae1c4613fb185524da691", "wid" : "1350", "name" : "bought stock",
>   "Symboles" : [ { "Name" : "AAA" } ] } 
>   { "_id" : ObjectId("57cd79b0287173b3468f6a36"), "userId" :
>   "57caf97b5ced6916b8970f5d", "wid" : "1350", "name" : "bought stock",
>   "Symboles" : [ { "Name" : "EXXI" }, { "Name" : "BSI" }, { "Name" :
>   "AMD" } ] }

[image]

[Solution](http://www.fourthbottle.com/2015/07/insert-details-into-bson-document-in-DOTNET.html)

```
var document = new BsonDocument();
        var arr = new BsonArray();
        document.Add("userId", UsersComboBox.SelectedItem.ToString());
        document.Add("wid", WIDTxt.Text.ToString());
        document.Add("name", NameComboBox.SelectedItem.ToString());
        foreach (var item in SymbolesListBox.SelectedItems)
        {
            arr.Add(new BsonDocument("Name", item.ToString()));
        }
        document.Add("Symboles", arr);

        await collectionWatchtbl.InsertOneAsync(document);
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: how to insert from listbox (Symboles Items) to collection?